# Asp.net: make div content partially bold

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a div whose innerHtml is set in my c# code (.cs).

```
<div id="feedbackRow" runat="server"></div>
```

**.cs**

```
feedbackRow.InnerHtml = "Activate your account to access reward points and unlock deals, discounts and bigger savings!.</br>You will find an ACTIVATE link within the body of the email.If you did not recevied the email into your inbox then please check your spam folders. </br>Thanks again for using ABC";
```

Here I want to make bold "ACTIVATE" word or say some of the text should be in different color/font in above statement. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe simple html:

```
feedbackRow.InnerHtml = "<strong>Activate</strong> ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place the text you want to be bolded between `<b>` or `<strong>` tags.

```
<b>text</b>
```

or

```
<strong>text</strong>
```